# How to map from iterable to non iterable & vice versa using MapStruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I have two classes - GeneralModel &  HotelInfo as shown below.
I wanted to map from HotelInfo to GeneralModel && from `List<HotelInfo>` to GeneralModel .
HotelDomain has exactly same no of attribute attributes & name as HotelInfo.

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GeneralModel {

    private String identificationNo;
    private List<HotelDomain> hotelDomains;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOTEL_INFO", schema = "hotel")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@ToString
public class HotelInfo {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String hotelName;
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HotelDomain {
  private String id;
  private String hotelName;
}
```

How to write mapper for below conversion using MapStruct.

```
GeneralModel listOfHotelInfoToGeneralModel(List<HotelInfo> hotelInfos);
```

&&

```
GeneralModel hotelInfoToGeneralModel(HotelInfo hotelInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Mapper Interface defining the mapping methods shown below

```
@Mapper
public interface HotelMapper {
    HotelMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(HotelMapper.class);
    
    @Mapping(source ="hotelInfos", target = "hotalDomains")
    GeneralModel listOfHotelInfoToGeneralModel(List<HotelInfo> hotelInfos);

    @Mapping(source ="hotelInfo", target = "hotalDomains")
    GeneralModel hotelInfoToGeneralModel(HotelInfo hotelInfo);
}
```

You can get the result from this method shown below

```
GeneralModel = generalModel = HotelMapper.INSTANCE.listOfHotelInfoToGeneralModel(hotelInfos);

GeneralModel = generalModel = HotelMapper.INSTANCE.hotelInfoToGeneralModel(hotelInfo);
```